# Search a model using Django Rest api returns null set

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have made a simple model which I want to query using Django rest API
I have made it an API seems to be online however isn't working
I am a beginner at Django and can't seem to find the error
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
# models.py

class TagsDB(models.Model):  # tags database links tags with each upload
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    title = models.ManyToManyField(Uploads)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag
```

---

```
# serializers.py

class TagsDBSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TagsDB
        fields = ('url', 'tag', 'upload_title')
```

---

```
# views.py

class TagsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TagsDBSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
 
        tag = self.kwargs['tag']
        return TagsDB.objects.filter(tag=tag)
```

---

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns=[
   url('^tags/(?P<tag>.+)/$', TagsList.as_view()),
]
```

I do get the API view but when I run a search with the URL
`http://localhost:8000/tags/tag=java`
which is supposed to search the DB for a tag with the name java, although such an object does exist, I get an empty set

[emptysetshown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIHxT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. URL should be `/tags/?tag=java` not `/tags/tag=java`
2. Tag is not in `kwargs` but in `query_params` for `request`. So you should do.

```
    tag = self.request.query_params.get('tag')
```

instead of `tag = self.kwargs['tag']`

Comment: it says page not found, the url pattern no longer matches

Comment: Change url pattern to `'^tags/$'`

Comment: i get this error
ImproperlyConfigured at /tags/
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "tagsdb-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
i tried to add a look up field in views by adding this line
 lookup_field= 'tag'
but error doesnt leave

Comment: so i't seems that your solution works only if i remove my foreign key